# Nested loop while distinct

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures

I have a table with the following COLS:  State, City, ZIP

I want to lookup all records that contain the same state, city, and zip for some statistics.

My thought was to do a distinct lookup on state to build a list of states in the table, then use that state to identify each city within that state, then use that combination of state and city to identify a zip, and lastly use that combination of state, city, zip to run a calculation.  ie.  count all records that have a common state, city, zip and determine the percentage of state records per zip code.

I want to create a stored procedure to loop through the entire table, running my calculation on each set of records that contain the same state, city, and zip.

Any directional nudge or shove would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kinds of statistics do you want to compute?

Comment: You should take a look at the `GROUP BY` option and computations sich as `SUM` and `AVG`: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: percentage calculations, that part's easy.  it's the nested looping through distinct lists that i'm having issues with.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) count, SUM(population)  population, state, city, zip
     FROM tab
 GROUP BY state, city, zip WITH ROLLUP
```

This should give you summaries of number of records and population by city/state/zip, and also rolled up summaries by state/city, state, and overall.

Here's a sqlfiddle with a few localities in it.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6c2e/1/0

(I'm not sure what stats you're trying to process so I threw in population as a guess.)